# HighCharts / HighStock rendering distortion error using addPoint

Tags: javascript, web-applications, highcharts

When using the [HighStock library](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock), I'm having problems dynamically adding a point to my highstock time series.
[image: First increment after initial render]

The initial timeseries renders well. But, using the [addPoint](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series) function, the first increment gives this wonky rendering error, as if the next incremental tick, is directly after the very first series tick in time (instead of after the last tick in that first render). It occurs when:

1. I do an initial `$(".selector").highcharts({:rangeSelector {:selected 1},

                                              :title {:text label},

                                              :chart {:zoomType "x"}

                                              :navigator {:adaptToUpdatedData true}

                                              :series [{:name label,

                                                        :data tlist

                                                        :marker {:enabled true, :radius 3},

                                                        :shadow true,

                                                        :tooltip {:valueDecimals 2}}]})` render (options structure is clojurescript). Then...
2. If I want to incrementally add to my time series using the [addPoint](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series) function.

The problem disappears when, after a number of incremental addPoints, the initial timeseries render is no longer visible. 
[image: Proper addPoint rendering after initial timeseries render is no longer visible]

Has anyone seen this before? Thanks 
Tim

Comment: Ok I fixed this. It was my fault. I was peeling the next data point from the wrong end of my list. And it was taking the entire length of the time series, before the redering was normal again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed this. It was my fault. I was peeling the next data point from the wrong end of my list. And it was taking the entire length of the time series, before the redering was normal again.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Data should be sorted by x ascending, so in case when you add new point, date should be the most late.